# Local git config not overriding global user for project

Tags: git, github, git-config

I have a global git user configured, but want to use a different user for a single git project.

Within that project, I've used `git config --local user.name "localuser"` and `git config --local user.email "localuser@example.com"` to set the local project's user and email.

However, when I try to push to my remote on github, I get this error:

```
remote: Permission to localuser/repo.git denied to globaluser.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/localuser/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Here's some output that might help with diagnosis:

`git remote -v`:

```
github  https://github.com/localuser/repo.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/localuser/repo.git (push)
```

`git config --list`:

```
user.name=globaluser
user.email=globaluser@example.com
...
```

`git config --local --list`:

```
user.name=localuser
user.email=localuser@example.com
...
```

`git config user.name`:

```
localuser
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had committed my changes and received a permission denied with my global user. Subsequently setting the local user did nothing, though `git config user.name` reported the correct local user.

What worked was ([courtesy of this google groups thread)](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/aH7sCmw94pg/eSil6DaieQYJ):

`git commit --amend --reset-author`

I presume the committed changes had the original author attached.

Comment: Yep, this is the solution. So what's happening is, the OP must have made some commits as the globaluser@example.com, then changed the email (and maybe username) to localuser@example.com. So he is not allowed to push commits with this previous email. The above amend command would change the author of those commits.

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me. I had to change the username and password under git:https://bitbucket.org in Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: This explained and eventually fixed the problem for me !!! I did not realize the problem is not the current git user, but who committed that history.

Comment: In case of many changes, you need to fix all commits instead of only the last one. After having fixed the user.name and user.email, try this:  `git rebase -r <last good commit sha> --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author' &&  git commit && git rebase --continue && git push -f`

Answer (score 16):

Tried numerous ways, spent many hours but nothing worked. I had to clear all the user finally:

`git config --local --unset credential.helper`
 `git config --global --unset credential.helper`
 `git config --system --unset credential.helper`

I'm now asked for my GitHub credentials on push again and can supply the correct user ID and password :)

If using windows then it can also be deleted by going to `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager`

Comment: unfortunately, didn't work on Mac for me :(

Answer (score 15):

If you are working on OSX with GitHub it might be a certificate problem. Your GitHub certificate, which remembers your user.name and user.email overrides the local config settings. One way to solve it, is to go to your keychain and remove the GitHub certificate.

Comment: what about windows. My Github global settings still override the local settings

Answer (score 3):

In my case, reset commit author does not work:

The problem is the combination of:

- My default ssh key id_rsa.pub was set on github by my global user
- My local user has not set the ssh-key on github

So your git will use the default id_rsa that linked to global user

The solution is:

- use ssh-keygen to generate a new ssh key, let's say id_2 & id_2.pub, add this ssh key to github
- `git config --add --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i <<<PATH_TO_SSH_KEY>>>'` will set the ssh option with new ssh key for local repo only

Done.

Comment: This worked for me after much struggling with separate github accounts for work and personal.

Comment: I had tried everything: 1) Remove from ssh-add -l all the keys; 2) Deleted all the key files on .ssh directory; 3) Deleted the ssh-keys on both GitHub accounts; 4) Generating news keys for both users; 4) Creating news registers for the new keys on GitHub for both accounts; 5) Changing the author for all commits on the local repository. But, somehow, git was still using the global user key inside the local repository, even after all of this. The "git config --add --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i <<<PATH_TO_SSH_KEY>>>'" command worked for me.

Comment: Note: make sure it's the private key and not the public ".pub" key you use for this.